# How do I optimize this flow for a news chatbot?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, chatbots

News UX flow

**user**: (clicks news from menu)

**bot**: pops 10 news items on a generic template with 3 buttons (read, share, settings)

**user**: (clicks settings)

**bot**: what time would you like to read news? Ex 2 pm

**user**: 23 30

**bot**: which days?
(Monday to Friday, Weekends, All days)

**user**: (selects all days)

**bot**: (shows a weburl link with a list of all the sites where the user can read news from and also lets the user add/remove news websites)

I designed the above flow for my chatbot that shows news. When the person clicks news ,I want to show them news inside a [generic template](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic) 
The carousel will have 10 news items and I need a way to let the person request more news if they want.

1. Get the time when the person wants news
2. Get the days of the week when the person would like to receive news, could be something custom as well like Sunday and Wednesday, a checkbox experience is needed here
3. Let the person view the list of sites from where they are getting news currently and remove/add other websites if required.

At the worst, I could have 3 screens inside a webview for each of the above goals and at the best, I could have a single screen just for the part where I show the person news websites. What is the right UX to achieve this goal?

Apologies, I am a newbie to chatbot UX and appreciate some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with a quote:

> Conversational UIs might mirror the way we naturally like to
>   communicate, but they actually required more mental load than
>   traditional GUIs. If you’re asking a user to engage in a conversation
>   instead of tapping a button or two, are you really making things any
>   easier? - [Intercom](https://blog.intercom.com/why-forms-arent-dead-yet/)

It sounds like a more traditional interface would suit your needs (and your users') better. An onboarding flow would allow your user to set their preferences and allows you to introduce them to your service. You can shape this like having a bit of a questionnaire session [like Virgin America did in this onboarding flow.](https://www.useronboard.com/how-virginamerica-onboards-new-users/?slide=67) This contains the same level of interaction, but keeps it within a 'setting up your account' vibe. You can also say here that your users can change/manage their settings at any time after the initial set-up.